# OAuth Login with Locust Load Testing

Tags: python, locust

I am load testing an application using Locust. It has an IP address rather than a web address, which is say 192.24.130.8080/app.

For the user to log in, the user is redirected to KeyCloak authentication service, that looks something like this:

http://192.24.130.8080/auth/realms/project/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=v5_prod&redirect_uri=http://192.24.130.8080/app/&response_type=code&scope=openid#/

I have the following code, using the username and log in password. However, when I change the password in the code (to the wrong password), the load testing runs just the same. This indicates to me that I am just hitting this re-direct page and not getting past it.

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        self.login()

    def on_stop(self):
        """ on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping """
        self.logout()

    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/app/&response_type=code&scope=openid#/", {"user":"user100", "password":"sun"})

    def logout(self):
        self.client.post("/app/&response_type=code&scope=openid#/", {"user":"user100", "password":"sun"})


    @task(3)
    def app(self):
        self.client.get("/index/#/")

    @task(1)


      def app2(self):
            self.client.get("/account/932507")

    class UserWait(HttpLocust):
        task_set = UserBehavior
        #1000 ms = 1 second
        min_wait = 2000
        max_wait = 3000
```

I'm not sure how to get pass this Keycloak oauth. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `self.client` is just a wrapper around a python-requests' session. You can look at [python-requests OAuth handling](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#oauth-2-and-openid-connect-authentication) directly for a solution.

Comment: 2.python-requests.org doesn't exist anymore. New equivalent of requests v3 is https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#oauth-2-and-openid-connect-authentication